# Issue with reading GATT Attribute on Android Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am trying to read a value from the GATT server and show it on my screen. I've gone through various tutorials and tried to find various means to solve this but I'm stumbling somewhere!

Some help will be appreciated.

Layout XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:text="Key : " android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/pubkey"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothGattActivity";
private static final String DEVICE_NAME = "PUNE\u0005\u0012\b";

/*
SECURITY SERVICE
 */
private static final UUID SECURITY_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("3E099914-293F-11E4-93BD-AFD0FE6D1DFD");
private static final UUID SECURITY_PUBLICKEY = UUID.fromString("3E099915-293F-11E4-93BD-AFD0FE6D1DFD");


private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private SparseArray<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;

private BluetoothGatt mConnectedGatt;

private  TextView publicKEY;

private ProgressDialog mProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);

    publicKEY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pubkey);


    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();

    mDevices = new SparseArray<BluetoothDevice>();

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgress.setCancelable(false);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /*
     * We need to enforce that Bluetooth is first enabled, and take the
     * user to settings to enable it if they have not done so.
     */
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        //Bluetooth is disabled
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBtIntent);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    /*
     * Check for Bluetooth LE Support.  In production, our manifest entry will keep this
     * from installing on these devices, but this will allow test devices or other
     * sideloads to report whether or not the feature exists.
     */
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No LE Support.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    clearDisplayValues();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //Make sure dialog is hidden
    mProgress.dismiss();
    //Cancel any scans in progress
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStopRunnable);
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStartRunnable);
    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Disconnect from any active tag connection
    if (mConnectedGatt != null) {
        mConnectedGatt.disconnect();
        mConnectedGatt = null;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Add the "scan" option to the menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //Add any device elements we've discovered to the overflow menu
    for (int i=0; i < mDevices.size(); i++) {
        BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.valueAt(i);
        menu.add(0, mDevices.keyAt(i), 0, device.getName());
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_scan:
            mDevices.clear();
            startScan();
            return true;
        default:
            //Obtain the discovered device to connect with
            BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.get(item.getItemId());
            Log.i(TAG, "Connecting to "+device.getName());
            /*
             * Make a connection with the device using the special LE-specific
             * connectGatt() method, passing in a callback for GATT events
             */
            mConnectedGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
            //Display progress UI
            mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Connecting to "+device.getName()+"..."));
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void clearDisplayValues() {
    publicKEY.setText("---");

}

private Runnable mStopRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        stopScan();
    }
};
private Runnable mStartRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startScan();
    }
};

private void startScan() {
    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    mHandler.postDelayed(mStopRunnable, 2500);
}

private void stopScan() {
    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

and all my callbacks are here

```
/* BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback */


@Override
public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
    Log.i(TAG, "New LE Device: " + device.getName() + " @ " + rssi);
    /*
     * We are looking for SensorTag devices only, so validate the name
     * that each device reports before adding it to our collection
     */
    if (DEVICE_NAME.equals(device.getName())) {
        mDevices.put(device.hashCode(), device);
        //Update the overflow menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

}

private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {


    private int mState = 0;

    private void reset()
    {
     mState= 0;
    }

    private void advance()
    {
        mState++;
    }

    private void enabled(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;

        switch(mState) {
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "Enable Public Key");
                characteristic = gatt.getService(SECURITY_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(SECURITY_PUBLICKEY);

                break;

            default:
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
                Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
                return;
        }


    }

    private void readData(BluetoothGatt gatt)
    {

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;

        switch (mState) {
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "Reading Public Key");
                characteristic = gatt.getService(SECURITY_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(SECURITY_PUBLICKEY);
                break;

            default:
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
                Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
                return;
        }
        gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);


    }

    private void enableNotif(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
        switch (mState) {
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "Setting Notification Public Key");
                characteristic = gatt.getService(SECURITY_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(SECURITY_PUBLICKEY);
                break;

            default:
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
                Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
                return;
        }

        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection State Change: " + status + " -> " + connectionState(newState));
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            /*
             * Once successfully connected, we must next discover all the services on the
             * device before we can read and write their characteristics.
             */
            gatt.discoverServices();
            mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Discovering Services..."));
        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            /*
             * If at any point we disconnect, send a message to clear the weather values
             * out of the UI
             */
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_CLEAR);
        } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            /*
             * If there is a failure at any stage, simply disconnect
             */
            gatt.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Services Discovered: " + status);
        mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Enabling Public Key..."));

        reset();
        enabled(gatt);

    }

    @Override
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,int status ) {
        if(SECURITY_PUBLICKEY.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null,MSG_PUBLICKEY,characteristic));
        }
        enableNotif(gatt);
        readData(gatt);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        //After writing the enable flag, next we read the initial value
        readData(gatt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Remote RSSI: " + rssi);
    }

    private String connectionState(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                return "Connected";
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                return "Disconnected";
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING:
                return "Connecting";
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                return "Disconnecting";
            default:
                return String.valueOf(status);
        }
    }

};



private static final int MSG_PROGRESS = 201;
private static final int MSG_DISMISS = 202;
private static final int MSG_CLEAR = 301;
private static final int MSG_PUBLICKEY = 101;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_PUBLICKEY:
                characteristic = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) msg.obj;
                if (characteristic.getValue() == null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error obtaining humidity value");
                    return;
                }
                updatePubKey(characteristic);
                break;

            case MSG_PROGRESS:
                mProgress.setMessage((String) msg.obj);
                if (!mProgress.isShowing()) {
                    mProgress.show();
                }
                break;
            case MSG_DISMISS:
                mProgress.hide();
                break;
            case MSG_CLEAR:
                clearDisplayValues();
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void updatePubKey(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
    for(byte byteChar : data)
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
    publicKEY.setText(new String(data)+" "+stringBuilder.toString());

}


}
```

Here's the log

```
Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41cc5460         time:10882957
BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
BluetoothGattActivity: New LE Device: null @ -83
BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
BluetoothGattActivity: New LE Device: PUNE @ -38
BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
BluetoothGattActivity: Connecting to PUNE
BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: B0:B4:48:BA:40:84, auto: false
BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=0bdf35a7-d4d0-4048-be15-a6cb030626f5
BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5                device=B0:B4:48:BA:40:84
BluetoothGattActivity: Connection State Change: 0 -> Connected
BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: B0:B4:48:BA:40:84
```

The services that I'm looking for are found here ..

```
onGetCharacteristic() - Device=B0:B4:48:BA:40:84 UUID=3e099919-293f-11e4-93bd-afd0fe6d1dfd
onGetCharacteristic() - Device=B0:B4:48:BA:40:84 UUID=3e099915-293f-11e4-93bd-afd0fe6d1dfd
onGetCharacteristic() - Device=B0:B4:48:BA:40:84 UUID=3e099916-293f-11e4-93bd-afd0fe6d1dfd
onGetCharacteristic() - Device=B0:B4:48:BA:40:84 UUID=3e099917-293f-11e4-93bd-afd0fe6d1dfd
```

Here's where the problem arises.

```
 D/BluetoothGattActivity: Services Discovered: 0
 D/BluetoothGattActivity: Enable Public Key
 W/BluetoothGatt: Unhandled exception in callback
 W/BluetoothGatt: java.lang.NullPointerException
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at gune.blegune.MainActivity$3.enabled(MainActivity.java:232)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at gune.blegune.MainActivity$3.onServicesDiscovered(MainActivity.java:314)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onSearchComplete(BluetoothGatt.java:295)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:215)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=B0:B4:48:BA:40:84
 D/BluetoothGattActivity: Connection State Change: 0 -> Disconnected
 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
```

Please. Some help will be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: What does your list of discovered services look like? The log you've shown indicates the characteristic UUID is valid, but there's nothing to indicate that your service UUID is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the line which is throwing the NPE:

characteristic = gatt.getService(SECURITY_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(SECURITY_PUBLICKEY);

So either

gatt is null or

gatt.getService(SECURITY_SERVICE)

is returning null.

Can you add some logging to find out which it is?

My guess is it's the second in which case I suggest you call getServices() on the BluetoothGatt object and log the UUID of each BluetoothGattService object in the resultant list to double check you have the service UUIDs you think you should have.

The spec for getService says "BluetoothGattService if supported, or null if the requested service is not offered by the remote device."